# using oracle object type with number attribute on odp.net

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, odp.net

After mapping Oracle Object Type as Class in C# using odp.net, while passing back the class to the stored procedure to insert the data into the table for all attributes with number data is empty. We are not receiving any exceptions. Code attached as below.
I am using oracle 9i and asp.net v2.

**new observation:**
I observe that if type of my variable be number(1) it insert properly with same structure as below, but for other cases like Number, Number(4), Number(3,2) all the value is null.

in below example below column are empty after insert:

1. ON_ORDER
2. ON_VERSION
3. ON_VERSION1
4. ON_VERSION

but other variable are inserted completely.

- when I read send items to my function in oracle DB, numbers are not included.
  Type structure:

  create or replace type CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE is object(
  OV_FIX_REF_NO     VARCHAR2(40),
  ON_ORDER     NUMBER(4),
  OV_OBJECT_NAME     VARCHAR2(100),
  OV_CATEGORY     VARCHAR2(12),
  OV_SCOPE     VARCHAR2(12),
  OV_TYPE     VARCHAR2(12),
  OV_LASTUPD_USER     VARCHAR2(40),
  OV_LASTUPD_PROG     VARCHAR2(40),
  OD_LASTUPD     DATE,
  OV_LOCATION     VARCHAR2(40),
  OV_REMARKS     VARCHAR2(4000),
  ON_VERSION     NUMBER(10,3),
  ON_VERSION1     NUMBER(10,3),
  OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION     VARCHAR2(5),
  OV_OBJECT_REGION     VARCHAR2(5),
  OV_OBJECT_TYPE     VARCHAR2(3),
  ON_VERSION2     NUMBER,
  ON_VERSION3     VARCHAR2(20)
  );
  /

Auto generated code with odp.net

```
    //

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated by a tool.
    //     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.3643
    //
    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    //     the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    namespace xxxBIZ {
        using System;
        using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
        using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
        using System

.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.Xml.Schema;


    public class CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE : INullable, IOracleCustomType, IXmlSerializable {

        private bool m_IsNull;

        private string m_OV_SCOPE;

        private string m_OV_REMARKS;

        private string m_OV_LASTUPD_USER;

        private Decimal m_ON_VERSION1;

        private bool m_ON_VERSION1IsNull;

        private string m_OV_FIX_REF_NO;

        private string m_OV_OBJECT_REGION;

        private string m_OV_OBJECT_NAME;

        private string m_OV_CATEGORY;

        private Decimal m_ON_ORDER;

        private bool m_ON_ORDERIsNull;

        private System.DateTime m_OD_LASTUPD;

        private bool m_OD_LASTUPDIsNull;

        private string m_OV_LASTUPD_PROG;

        private string m_OV_LOCATION;

        private string m_ON_VERSION3;

        private Decimal m_ON_VERSION2;

        private bool m_ON_VERSION2IsNull;

        private Decimal m_ON_VERSION;

        private bool m_ON_VERSIONIsNull;

        private string m_OV_OBJECT_TYPE;

        private string m_OV_TYPE;

        private string m_OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION;

        public CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE() {
            // TODO : Add code to initialise the object
            this.m_ON_VERSION1IsNull = true;
            this.m_ON_ORDERIsNull = true;
            this.m_OD_LASTUPDIsNull = true;
            this.m_ON_VERSION2IsNull = true;
            this.m_ON_VERSIONIsNull = true;
        }

        public CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE(string str) {
            // TODO : Add code to initialise the object based on the given string 
        }

        public virtual bool IsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_IsNull;
            }
        }

        public static CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE Null {
            get {
                CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE obj = new CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE();
                obj.m_IsNull = true;
                return obj;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_SCOPE")]
        public string OV_SCOPE {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_SCOPE;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_SCOPE = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_REMARKS")]
        public string OV_REMARKS {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_REMARKS;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_REMARKS = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_LASTUPD_USER")]
        public string OV_LASTUPD_USER {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_LASTUPD_USER;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_LASTUPD_USER = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ON_VERSION1")]
        public Decimal ON_VERSION1 {
            get {
                return this.m_ON_VERSION1;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ON_VERSION1 = value;
            }
        }

        public bool ON_VERSION1IsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_ON_VERSION1IsNull;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ON_VERSION1IsNull = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_FIX_REF_NO")]
        public string OV_FIX_REF_NO {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_FIX_REF_NO;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_FIX_REF_NO = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_OBJECT_REGION")]
        public string OV_OBJECT_REGION {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_OBJECT_REGION;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_OBJECT_REGION = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_OBJECT_NAME")]
        public string OV_OBJECT_NAME {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_OBJECT_NAME;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_OBJECT_NAME = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_CATEGORY")]
        public string OV_CATEGORY {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_CATEGORY;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_CATEGORY = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ON_ORDER")]
        public Decimal ON_ORDER {
            get {
                return this.m_ON_ORDER;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ON_ORDER = value;
            }
        }

        public bool ON_ORDERIsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_ON_ORDERIsNull;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ON_ORDERIsNull = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OD_LASTUPD")]
        public System.DateTime OD_LASTUPD {
            get {
                return this.m_OD_LASTUPD;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OD_LASTUPD = value;
            }
        }

        public bool OD_LASTUPDIsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_OD_LASTUPDIsNull;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OD_LASTUPDIsNull = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_LASTUPD_PROG")]
        public string OV_LASTUPD_PROG {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_LASTUPD_PROG;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_LASTUPD_PROG = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_LOCATION")]
        public string OV_LOCATION {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_LOCATION;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_LOCATION = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ON_VERSION3")]
        public string ON_VERSION3 {
            get {
                return this.m_ON_VERSION3;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ON_VERSION3 = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ON_VERSION2")]
        public Decimal ON_VERSION2 {
            get {
                return this.m_ON_VERSION2;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ON_VERSION2 = value;
            }
        }

        public bool ON_VERSION2IsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_ON_VERSION2IsNull;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ON_VERSION2IsNull = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ON_VERSION")]
        public Decimal ON_VERSION {
            get {
                return this.m_ON_VERSION;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ON_VERSION = value;
            }
        }

        public bool ON_VERSIONIsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_ON_VERSIONIsNull;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ON_VERSIONIsNull = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_OBJECT_TYPE")]
        public string OV_OBJECT_TYPE {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_OBJECT_TYPE;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_OBJECT_TYPE = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_TYPE")]
        public string OV_TYPE {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_TYPE;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_TYPE = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION")]
        public string OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION {
            get {
                return this.m_OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION;
            }
            set {
                this.m_OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual void FromCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, System.IntPtr pUdt) {
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_SCOPE", this.OV_SCOPE);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_REMARKS", this.OV_REMARKS);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_LASTUPD_USER", this.OV_LASTUPD_USER);
            if ((ON_VERSION1IsNull == false)) {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION1", this.ON_VERSION1);
            }
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_FIX_REF_NO", this.OV_FIX_REF_NO);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_OBJECT_REGION", this.OV_OBJECT_REGION);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_OBJECT_NAME", this.OV_OBJECT_NAME);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_CATEGORY", this.OV_CATEGORY);
            if ((ON_ORDERIsNull == false)) {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "ON_ORDER", this.ON_ORDER);
            }
            if ((OD_LASTUPDIsNull == false)) {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OD_LASTUPD", this.OD_LASTUPD);
            }
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_LASTUPD_PROG", this.OV_LASTUPD_PROG);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_LOCATION", this.OV_LOCATION);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION3", this.ON_VERSION3);
            if ((ON_VERSION2IsNull == false)) {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION2", this.ON_VERSION2);
            }
            if ((ON_VERSIONIsNull == false)) {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION", this.ON_VERSION);
            }
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_OBJECT_TYPE", this.OV_OBJECT_TYPE);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_TYPE", this.OV_TYPE);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION", this.OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION);
        }

        public virtual void ToCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, System.IntPtr pUdt) {
            this.OV_SCOPE = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_SCOPE")));
            this.OV_REMARKS = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_REMARKS")));
            this.OV_LASTUPD_USER = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_LASTUPD_USER")));
            this.ON_VERSION1IsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION1");
            if ((ON_VERSION1IsNull == false)) {
                this.ON_VERSION1 = ((Decimal)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION1")));
            }
            this.OV_FIX_REF_NO = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_FIX_REF_NO")));
            this.OV_OBJECT_REGION = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_OBJECT_REGION")));
            this.OV_OBJECT_NAME = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_OBJECT_NAME")));
            this.OV_CATEGORY = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_CATEGORY")));
            this.ON_ORDERIsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "ON_ORDER");
            if ((ON_ORDERIsNull == false)) {
                this.ON_ORDER = ((Decimal)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "ON_ORDER")));
            }
            this.OD_LASTUPDIsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "OD_LASTUPD");
            if ((OD_LASTUPDIsNull == false)) {
                this.OD_LASTUPD = ((System.DateTime)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OD_LASTUPD")));
            }
            this.OV_LASTUPD_PROG = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_LASTUPD_PROG")));
            this.OV_LOCATION = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_LOCATION")));
            this.ON_VERSION3 = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION3")));
            this.ON_VERSION2IsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION2");
            if ((ON_VERSION2IsNull == false)) {
                this.ON_VERSION2 = ((Decimal)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION2")));
            }
            this.ON_VERSIONIsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION");
            if ((ON_VERSIONIsNull == false)) {
                this.ON_VERSION = ((Decimal)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "ON_VERSION")));
            }
            this.OV_OBJECT_TYPE = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_OBJECT_TYPE")));
            this.OV_TYPE = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_TYPE")));
            this.OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION")));
        }

        public virtual void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader) {
            // TODO : Read Serialized Xml Data
        }

        public virtual void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer) {
            // TODO : Serialize object to xml data
        }

        public virtual XmlSchema GetSchema() {
            // TODO : Implement GetSchema
            return null;
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            // TODO : Return a string that represents the current object
            return "";
        }

        public static CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE Parse(string str) {
            // TODO : Add code needed to parse the string and get the object represented by the string
            return new CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE();
        }
    }

    // Factory to create an object for the above class
    [OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute("PENTACMS.CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE")]
    public class CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPEFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory {

        public virtual IOracleCustomType CreateObject() {
            CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE obj = new CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE();
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

> insert code

```
 private void INSERT_INTO_CMMT_OBJECTS(CMMT_FIX_MASTER_TYPE fixMaster, DateTime dt)
{
    CMMT_OBJECTS_COL cmmt_obj_col = new CMMT_OBJECTS_COL();
    CMMT_OBJECTS_COLFactory objList = new CMMT_OBJECTS_COLFactory();
    CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE[] objColl = (CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE[])objList.CreateArray(DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox TextBoxN_ORDER = (TextBox)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("N_ORDER");
        TextBox TextBoxV_OBJECT_NAME = (TextBox)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("V_OBJECT_NAME");
        DropDownList DrpV_TYPE = (DropDownList)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("V_TYPE");
        DropDownList DrpV_LOCATION = (DropDownList)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("V_LOCATION");
        DropDownList DrpV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION = (DropDownList)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("V_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION");
        DropDownList DrpV_OBJECT_REGION = (DropDownList)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("V_OBJECT_REGION");
        TextBox TextBoxV_REMARKS = (TextBox)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("V_REMARKS");
        TextBox TextBoxN_VERSION = (TextBox)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[8].FindControl("N_VERSION");
        TextBox TextBoxN_VERSION1 = (TextBox)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[9].FindControl("N_VERSION1");
        TextBox TextBoxN_VERSION2 = (TextBox)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[10].FindControl("N_VERSION2");
        TextBox TextBoxN_VERSION3 = (TextBox)DGV_OBJ_LIST.Rows[i].Cells[11].FindControl("N_VERSION3");

        objColl[i] = new CMMT_OBJECTS_TYPE();
        if(TextBoxN_ORDER.Text != "")
            objColl[i].ON_ORDER = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxN_ORDER.Text);
        objColl[i].OV_OBJECT_NAME = TextBoxV_OBJECT_NAME.Text;
        objColl[i].OV_TYPE = DrpV_TYPE.SelectedValue;
        objColl[i].OV_LASTUPD_USER= smsUser.UserID;
        objColl[i].OV_LASTUPD_PROG = programName;
        objColl[i].OD_LASTUPD = dt;
        objColl[i].OD_LASTUPDIsNull = false;
        objColl[i].OV_LOCATION = DrpV_LOCATION.SelectedValue;
        objColl[i].OV_REMARKS = TextBoxV_REMARKS.Text;
        if(TextBoxN_VERSION.Text != "")
            objColl[i].ON_VERSION = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxN_VERSION.Text);
        if (TextBoxN_VERSION1.Text != "")
            objColl[i].ON_VERSION1 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxN_VERSION1.Text);
        if (TextBoxN_VERSION2.Text != "")
            objColl[i].ON_VERSION2 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxN_VERSION2.Text);
        objColl[i].ON_VERSION3 = TextBoxN_VERSION3.Text;
        objColl[i].OV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION = DrpV_OBJECT_CLASSIFICATION.SelectedValue;
        objColl[i].OV_OBJECT_REGION = DrpV_OBJECT_REGION.SelectedValue;
    }
    cmmt_obj_col.Value = objColl;
    fixMaster.OC_CMMT_OBJECTS_COL = cmmt_obj_col;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making a smaller table and proc with just the field type you are having trouble with?  It would be easier for you to narrow down your problem, and way more reasonable to ask people to look through a small code snippet then the huge body of code you posted.

Comment: @TomHalladay, Thanks tom for reply, Juat check int value, all of my int value are started with ON_, I understand that all of my num variable are not inserting :( it is look like some casting problem is there.

Comment: @TomHalladay: my problem is everything inserting properly except int column(number)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer, after execute your parameter

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it caused ToCustomObject function from your type class that has been generated by odp.net in VS and in that function for all the Data and Number you have a parameter with same name of your numeric or data parameter as bool type. this varriable started with you column name and ended with IsNull

```
OD_SUBMITTEDIsNull
```

after you set value of your DATA or Number variable you should set this parameter as true.

That's all :)

OD_SUBMITTEDIsNull = true;